# How to specify fillfactor for a table in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, alembic

Let's say I have a simple table. In raw SQL it looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events (id INT PRIMARY KEY) WITH (fillfactor=60);
```

My question is how to specify fillfactor **for a table** using `sqlalchemy` declarative base?
Of course I can achieve that by using raw SQL in `sqlalchemy` like `execute("ALTER TABLE events SET (fillfactor=60)")`, but I'm interested whether there is a way to do that using native `sqlalchemy` tools.

I've tried the following approach, but that didnt't work:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class SimpleExampleTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'events'
    __table_args__ = {'comment': 'events table', "fillfactor": 60}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

```
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'fillfactor'
```

Looking through documentation I've managed to find information only about fillfactor usage in **indexes**.

My environment:

- python 3.9
- sqlalchemy 1.3.22
- PostgreSQL 11.6

Comment: have you tired `postgresql_fillfactor`

Answer (score 1):

Tbh, have the same question, and the only thing I found which is related to the `fillfactor` in the SQLAlchemy docs is the one with index ([link to docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#index-storage-parameters)):

> PostgreSQL allows storage parameters to be set on indexes. The storage
> parameters available depend on the index method used by the index.
> Storage parameters can be specified on Index using the postgresql_with
> keyword argument:
>
> `Index('my_index', my_table.c.data, postgresql_with={"fillfactor": 50})`

But it seems, there is no setting option where you can set the `fillfactor` directly for the table.

But there is still an option to run the raw SQL query (as the alembic migration, let's say):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable SET (fillfactor = 70);
```

> Note that setting `fillfactor` on an existing table will not rearrange
> the data, it will only apply to future inserts. But you can use
> `VACUUM` to rewrite the table, which will respect the new `fillfactor`
> setting.

The previous quote is taken from [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20setting%20fillfactor%20on%20an%20existing%20table%20will%20not%20rearrange%20the%20data%2C%20it%20will%20only%20apply%20to%20future%20INSERTs.%20But%20you%20can%20use%20VACUUM%20(FULL)%20or%20CLUSTER%20to%20rewrite%20the%20table%2C%20which%20will%20respect%20the%20new%20fillfactor%20setting.)

Answer (score 1):

Extending the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73223863/5320906) from [Max Kapustin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13760443/max-kapustin), you can use an [event listener](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/event.html#events) to automatically execute the `ALTER TABLE` statement when the table is created.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql:///test', echo=True, future=True)

tablename = 't65741211'
tbl = sa.Table(
        tablename,
        sa.MetaData(),
        sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
        listeners=[
            (
                'after_create',
                sa.schema.DDL(
                    f"""ALTER TABLE "{tablename}" SET (fillfactor = 70)"""
                ),
            )
        ],
)

tbl.drop(engine, checkfirst=True)
tbl.create(engine)
```